# Hello world encryption recursive call to main

Tags: c, recursion, program-entry-point

I have found a code rather strange, I say that because makes a recursive call to main which is something new for me therefore I ask for information about it and most importantly I would like a detailed explanation of the method used to print hello world, if not too much trouble. The program is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    static int i = 0xc;    
    putchar(*("\x1\x22\x22\x70\x65\x6f\x76\x6e\x21\x62\x6d\x70\x69" + i--) - 1); 
    return  i ? main() : 0;    
}
```

thx

Comment: Trick programming which has no practical use whatsoever. The code works, what problem to you have?

Comment: I think the author wimped out. He forgot to finish the noodle-baker using `return i && main();`. Regarding the actual question, create some temporaries and step through this single-line in a debugger. It will become evident how it works.

Comment: Do not try to understand how that code works.... just forgot. Learn writing understandable code :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly legal to call `main` recursively.

The output is `"hola mundo!!"`

The key string is

```
"\x1\x22\x22\x70\x65\x6f\x76\x6e\x21\x62\x6d\x70\x69"
```

which is the same as

```
"\0!!odnum aloh"
```

*shifted by one character* (i.e. with `i` instead of `h`, `p` instead of `o`, etc.), i.e.:

```
"\x1\"\"peovn!bmpi"
```

Then,

```
(*("\x1\x22\x22\x70\x65\x6f\x76\x6e\x21\x62\x6d\x70\x69" + i--)
```

is the same as

```
"\x1\"\"peovn!bmpi"[i--]
```

So every `putchar` outputs one character of the string minus one, from right to left.

Comment: It's perfectly *legal* to call `main` recursively. I wouldn't call it "OK".

Comment: @AlexD because the characters are shifted one position  if key string is "\0!!odnum aloh"

Comment: @cheroky Let's take just the first word for simplicity. The characters in the code are: `"x62\x6d\x70\x69"`, same as `"bmpi"`. If we decrease all characters by 1, we get `"aloh"`. (By "_shifting by one character_" I mean just "_increasing/decreasing by one_". It has nothing to do with left/right shifting.)

Comment: @AlexD  because not directly save "bmpi" and avoid displacement?

Comment: @cheroky Maybe I did not understand your question. You could use "x62\x6d\x70\x69" or `"bmpi"`. These are just two ways to write _the same_ string.

Comment: I refer to that shifting characters Is not it possible display them directly: "aloh"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73705/discussion-between-cheroky-and-alexd).